# Check if a string has a capital letter in Django?

Tags: python, django, string

If I have a string "Hello", how do I check if the string has at least one capital letter and one lowercase letter in Django?

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Try this (s is your string):

```
set(s)-set(s.lower())!=set() and set(s)-set(s.upper())!=set()
```

It will return True if your string includes at least one lowercase and one uppercase and False otherwise

For example:

```
>>> s='test'
>>> set(s)-set(s.lower())!=set() and set(s)-set(s.upper())!=set()
False
>>> s='TeSt'
>>> set(s)-set(s.lower())!=set() and set(s)-set(s.upper())!=set()
True
>>> s='TEST'
>>> set(s)-set(s.lower())!=set() and set(s)-set(s.upper())!=set()
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> pw1 = "Hello"
>>> pw2 = "hello"
>>> any(char.isupper() for char in pw1) and any(char.islower() for char in pw1)
True
>>> any(char.isupper() for char in pw2) and any(char.islower() for char in pw2)
False
```

Strings are iterable in Python, so we can test each character in the string and see if any of them are uppercase, and then do the same to see if any are lowercase. We then use `and` to see if they're both true.